# center image inside background wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a password box eye in wpf, I need the eye icon in the middle but it goes to left top corner, how to fix?

Here my xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="button"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="215,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30">
                            <Button.Background >
                                <ImageBrush  ImageSource="../pics/eye3.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
                                    <ImageBrush.Transform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
                                    </ImageBrush.Transform>
                                </ImageBrush>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Link for the eye image download: [link](https://icons8.com/icon/set/eye/ios-glyphs),

Smartio bean

Comment: Why don't you simply put an Image element in the Button's Content?

Comment: I don't want that the image would be stretched, I need to modify the size of if, I mean I want it in the middle of the button

Comment: `<Image Stretch="None" ...>` or fixed Width/Height. It is centered by default.

Comment: See code above I made `<Image Stretch="None">`

Comment: No you didn't. That is an ImageBrush in the Background, not an Image in the Content.

Comment: Please post answer with code, it's hard to understand like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an ImageBrush in the Button's Background, you could simply put an Image element in the Button's Content:

```
<Button ...>
    <Image Source="../pics/eye3.png" Stretch="None">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Button>
```